# UITableViewCell swipe change content with nib file

Tags: ios, swift, swipe, nib, uitableview

Can iOS `UITableView` change or populate different `UITableViewCell` object's content with different `.xib` files, so that when the user swipes, content will change at the current swiped row.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1) Recognize swipe with UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Use UIScrollView in each cell and write some logic based on swipe handler.

2) Use some gallery-like library. For example, GBInfiniteScrollView ( 
[Github](https://github.com/gblancogarcia/GBInfiniteScrollView)

Comment: You can start from here
 http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content, section "Paging with UIScrollView". The article has a downloadable example project.
This code won't solve your problem completely but will give you some ideas about paging with UIScrollView.